# How to get packageName in companion object?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-bundle, kotlin-companion

I want to make a unique key when i send a intent/bundle to new Activity/Fragment in Android. 
So, i decided to use `packageName`.

```
companion object {
    val MY_UNIQUE_KEY = "${this@Companion::class.java.packageName}MY_KEY"

    fun newInstance(user: User): UserFragment = UserFragment().apply {
        arguments = bundleOf(
            MY_UNIQUE_KEY  to user
        )
    }
}
```

But, in this case, i couldn't use `this@Companion::class.java.packageName` because the android system warns me that it requires API 31(mine supports API 21).

How can i make it? or could you tell me another good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `package` field for the same. Like so:

```
val MY_UNIQUE_KEY = "${this@Companion::class.java.`package`?.name.orEmpty()}MY_KEY"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
By the way, i realized that `this@Companion::class.java.name` is much specific and unique than `this@Companion::class.java.`package`?.name.orEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
fun newInstance(user: User): UserFragment = UserFragment().apply {
    arguments = bundleOf(
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.S) {
            "${javaClass.packageName}MY_KEY" to user
        } else {
            "${javaClass.getPackage()?.name.orEmpty()}MY_KEY" to user
        }
    )
}
```

OR just create Unique Constant `String` value for each `Fragment/Activity`.